# Magento Add To Cart Multi Product at a time

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, addtocart

How to add multi product into cart in magento.

Comment: have you tried someting?

Answer (score 1):

```
copy this file and past your list.phtml in catalog/product

<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg">
<?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>

 <!--  <button class="button btn-allcart" type="button" title="Add all to cart" onclick="AddAllToCart();"> -->

    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="AddAllToCart();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
          <button onclick="AddAllToCart();" class="button btn-cart" type="button" title="Add all to cart">
<span>
<span>Add all to cart</span>
</span>
</button>

    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php echo $_product->getId();?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>

                    <fieldset class="add-to-cart-box">
                        <input type="hidden" name="products[]" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
                        <legend><?php echo $this->__('Add Items to Cart') ?></legend>
                        <span class="qty-box"><label for="qtybox_id_<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label>
                        <!--<input name="qty<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" type="text" class="input-text qty" id="qtybox_id_<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" maxlength="12" value="" />--></span>
                       <!--<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox add" name="add_<?php echo $_iterator; ?>" id="add_<?php echo $_iterator; ?>" />-->


<!------------------------------------------------- Start 1st part Add to cart Multiple products ------------------------------------------------->

<input type="hidden" class="add" name="url_<?php echo $_iterator; ?>" id="url_<?php echo $_iterator; ?>" value="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" />
<?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
     <input type="text" class="input-text qty" name="qty_<?php echo $_iterator; ?>" id="qty_<?php echo $_iterator; ?>" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>" />
<!----------------------------------------------- End 1st part Add to cart Multiple products ------------------------------------------------------->


<?php endif; ?>

                    </fieldset>
                       <!-- <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                       -->
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

<!------------------------------------------------- Start 2nd part Add to cart Multiple products ------------------------------------------------->

        <script type="text/javascript">
    function processNext(urls, i) {
        var next = i + 1;
        $('processing-text').update('Processing item ' + next);
        if (next < urls.size()) {
            new Ajax.Request(urls[i], {
              method: 'get',
              onComplete: function(transport) {
                processNext(urls, next);
              }
            });
        } else {
            new Ajax.Request(urls[i], {
              method: 'get',
              onComplete: function(transport) {
                window.location.href='checkout/cart'
              }
            });
        }
    }

    function addItemsToCart() {
        $('add-items-to-cart').hide();
        $('waiting').show();

        var addToCartUrls = [];
        $$('input.add').each(function(e){
var id = e.readAttribute('id').split('_')[1];
//alert(id);
var qty = Number($('qty_' + id).value);
            if(qty > 0) {
//alert(qty);
                addToCartUrls.push($('url_' + id).value + 'qty/' + qty);
            }
        });

        if (addToCartUrls.size() > 0) {
            processNext(addToCartUrls, 0);
        } else {
            $('add-items-to-cart').show();
            $('waiting').hide();
            alert('Please add quantity for product then click add to cart button');
        }
    }
</script>
<!----------------------------------------------- End 2nd part Add to cart Multiple products ------------------------------------------------------->

    <?php endforeach; ?>
<!------------------------------------------------- Start 3rd part Add to cart Multiple products ------------------------------------------------->

    <div style="margin-bottom:5px; text-align:right;">
    <button id="add-items-to-cart" class="form-button" onclick="addItemsToCart()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add Items to Cart') ?></span></button>
    <div id="waiting" style="height:22px; display:none; line-height:22px;"><span id="processing-text">Processing...</span> <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl().'ajaxlog_loader.gif'; ?>" width="22" height="22" style="display:inline; vertical-align:middle;"/></div></div>

    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('shopping-cart-table')</script>

<!----------------------------------------------- End 3rd part Add to cart Multiple products ------------------------------------------------------->

<button onclick="AddAllToCart();" class="button btn-allcart" title="Add all to cart" type="button"><span><span>Add all to cart</span></span></button>



    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <div class="actions">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```